# Use javascript to wrap container in link to the first <a> href in the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Site: [bit.ly/20ZsQA0](http://bit.ly/20ZsQA0)

I would like to use javascript to wrap the entire colored boxes in the first link ( href) used in the box code itself. For example if I link "Learn More" to google.com the entire box should be linked/clickable to that same link. The code below successfully links the box but it goes to a wrong link. Any ideas on how I can refactor this code.

```
$('.L3BoxNavHolder li').on('click', function () { window.location = $('.L3BoxNavHolder li a:first', this).attr('href'); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *inside* `this` matching that selector (given that `this` is actually in the middle of it).

You simply need to look for `a:first`:

```
$('.L3BoxNavHolder li').on('click', function () { 
  window.location.href = $('a:first', this).attr('href'); 
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/WQmWPN

Comment: Using that code the link still goes to /undefined
bit.ly/20ZsQA0

Comment: Please edit the question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including HTML that causes this JS to fail. The sample HTML on CodePen doesn't cause the error.

Comment: I sent the link. I had to preserve console log which is as follows:
- GET http://wilshire.priworks.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ custom.js?cdv=46:11jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?cdv=46:3074elemData.handle @ jquery.js?cdv=46:2750
jquery.js?cdv=46:8492
- Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
- Navigated to http://wilshire.priworks.com/undefined

Comment: I figured out the issue...DNN inserts a blank a href and it was using that a href instead. I made the selector more specific. Thanks!